# How can I get a specific link using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the specific link from this

```
<a href="/doi/10.1021/ed500712k" title="Next" class="header_contnav-next">
            <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
        </a>
```

I'm only able to find all the links within the page and it would be helpful to extract this specific one.

Thank you !

Comment: Can you show us how you've tried to solve this so far? How are you finding all of the links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you're using .find_all() function to get links, to find a specific item, you should use .find() function instead of that. If you're sure that only this one has the "class" variable set to "header_contnav-next", then all you need to do is to specify it in dictionary format:

```
soup.find("a", {"class": "header_contnav-next"})['href']
```

Comment: Right. I was using .find_all() so obviously I didn't get the right answer. Thanks very much !

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark my answer as solved so anybody else can use it :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you just need to find the `<a>` element and, save it to `some_variable` and then use `some_variable.href`.

Can't give you more information from what you've provided.